# How to publish gradle subproject to Maven local repository?

Tags: java, gradle

My build.gradle looks like this

```
configurations {
    bukkitPlugin
    ...
}

dependencies {
    bukkitPlugin(project(':IslandCraft-Bukkit'))
    bukkitPlugin(project(':IslandCraft-NMS-v1_12_R1'))
    bukkitPlugin(project(':IslandCraft-NMS-v1_13_R1'))
}


task bukkit(type: ShadowJar) {
    description = 'Create the IslandCraft Bukkit plugin JAR'
    group = project.group
    baseName = project.name
    appendix = 'Bukkit'
    version = project.version
    configurations = [ project.configurations.bukkitPlugin ]
    from {
        project.configurations.bukkitPlugin
    }
    relocate 'org.mcstats', 'com.github.hoqhuuep.islandcraft.mcstats'
}

publishing {
    publications {
        bukkitPlugin(MavenPublication) { publication ->
            shadow.component(publication)
        }
    }
}
```

`gradle bukkit` works fine and builds all that I need but `gradle publishToMavenLocal` saves jar with META-INF only on my local repository. How can I install the build to local repository?